301 redirects for individual pages where the main URL is redirected to a landing page
I have
https://olddomain.com redirected to https://newdomain.com/landing-page
and a whole list of other pages;
https://olddomain.com/page1
https://olddomain.com/page2
https://olddomain.com/page3
...that are redirected to individual other pages
how do I do this in .htaccess?

What have you tried?

in the end it was fairly straightforward as long as I used RewriteCond and RewriteRule rather than Redirect

As I was unable to find anything definitive on the web, this is my solution (basically arrived at by adding the redirects in cPanel redirection and then copying the pattern into htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$

#redirect home page to a specific page
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://newdomain.com/landing-page/" [R=301,L]

#redirect individual pages to new destinations
RewriteRule ^old-page-1/$ "https://newdomain.com/new-page-1" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-page-2/$ "https://newdomain.com/new-page-2" [R=301,L]

...

